# I2C SCL high state inconsistent

Tags: i2c

I am using a MCU to read/write to EEPROM, using i2c. The SCL clock high state duration is inconsistent. See the attached screenshot. [cyan is SDA, yellow is SCL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiwcf.jpg)
When the SCL is held in high state for too long, it could cause data error.

Why is the SCL clock inconsistent?

Comment: There should be some bug in your code! Which you haven't shown.

Comment: to solve this issue, need to disable interrupt when the SCL state is pulled high.